# Not able to retrieve ajax data in controller - Laravel 5.2, AngularJs

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, controller, laravel-5

I want to retrieve the data values in a controller function which I am sending through ajax, but unable to achieve it.

Here is my ajax code -

```
var postArg = {startDate:localStorage.getItem('startDate'), endDate:localStorage.getItem('endDate'), startTime:localStorage.getItem('startTime'), endTime:localStorage.getItem('endTime')}

    $http.post('checkvehicleavailability', angular.toJson(postArg), {    
        withCredentials: true,      
        headers: {'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }           
    }).success(function(data, status) {                                    
        console.log(data);          
    });
```

and here is my laravel controller function -

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use App\User;
 use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Input;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;




class VehicleController extends Controller
{
    public function vehicleAvailability(){


    $request = new Request();
    $data = $request->all();
    var_dump($data);
    die();

  }
}
```

Here is my route -

```
Route::post('checkvehicleavailability','VehicleController@vehicleAvailability');
```

When I check with postman, then I get this response-

```
array(0) { }
```

I have seen many stackoverflow links but none of them worked out for me. Please someone help me to retrieve the data.

Comment: you are not sending your CSRF token which laravel requires for all post data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//ajax call
    `$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{URL::to('checkvehicleavailability')}}",
                        data: {datahere},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                            console.log(response);
                        }
             });`

// for routing

```
Route::post('checkvehicleavailability','VehicleController@vehicleAvailability');
```

//for controller

```
class VehicleController extends Controller
{
public function vehicleAvailability(){
$inputs = Input::all();
return Response::json( $inputs);

}
}
```

//now you will be able to see ur input data in console.

//dont forget to include in controller

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;`